# What is the "wait' indicator on the commits page?

Tags: gitlab

When looking at the commits page for my application, I see a rotating icon suggesting that it is waiting for something

[image]

It is always in that rotating state. Hovering above it does not provide any information.

**What indicator is it?**

Comment: Never used gitlab, however it looks like a [pull request icon](https://www.google.com/search?q=pull+request+icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a spinner, and is about to change in the next GitLab release (possibly July 2019), as shown in [MR 25186](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/25186#note_141832173), as part of [issue 20084](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20084)

[image: new spinner]

It comes from [`gitlab-org/gitlab-ce` commit a7d26f0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/a7d26f00c35b945199d40332349f463043ae6122), from [MR 13713](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/13713) for GitLab 10.5 (Feb. 2018)

[image: Spinner in action]

This was from [issue 2383](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2383)

> ### Add link on commit page to merge request that introduced that commit
>
> We can now do this relatively easily, since every MR is copied to `refs/merge-requests/:iid/head`, and we already have the list of branches in which a commit occurs.
> We can see if any refs like that are in that list, parse the IID out of there, look up the MR by IID, and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

It must have been a glitch in GitLab - I looked at other commits in other projects and all of them show

[image]

Coming back to the initial page I see that it also states `No related merge requests found`. I assume it is linked with pull requests.

I have seen this rotating logo many times (usually on fresh commits) which stayed for an extended time (I do not know how long, I never paid attention to the page when the logo was not rotating) but they persisted page refreshes and browser restarts.